# Styling an imported component with Styled Components causes Jest to crash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, styled-components

When I import a component (`react-slider`) and style it via Styled Components, Jest crashes.

The code for this as as follows:

My `Component.styles.js` file:

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'
import ReactSlider from 'react-slider'

const StyledReactSlider = styled(ReactSlider)`
...CSS here
`
```

My Component is as follows:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import * as Styled from './Component.styles'

...Lots of code

<Styled.StyledReactSlider
barClassName={'slider-bar'}
handleClassName={'slider-handle'}
withBars
max={max}
value={value}
onChange={onChange}
/>

...Lots more code
```

And finally, my very simple test file:

```
import React from 'react'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'

import 'jest-styled-components'

import MyComponent from './MyComponent'

describe('Component Tests ', () => {
  it(`should render the <MyComponent /> default correctly`, () => {
    const component = mount(<MyComponent />)
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot()
    component.unmount()
  })
})
```

The results from this is a large error which looks like node is running out of memory (JavaScript heap out of memory messages), the terminal then hangs.

This is using `react-slider 0.11.2`, `styled-components 4.3.1` and `jest 24.8.0`.

**Note**: The test runs fine if I don't import the component into the styles file, so I think I must be doing something wrong with the imported component styling?